# ActionBar within Coordinator Layout goes away on custom searchview focus

Tags: android, searchview, android-coordinatorlayout

So, I have seen various questions on this forum and have tried a number of solutions but none have worked so far. Also, none of the previous have used Coordinator Layout. Basically I have a custom searchview outside of the actionbar which searches within a recylerview list. However, upon SearchView focus, the softkeyboard opens and hides the entire ActionBar and some part of the top of recyclerview, which does not show up even on scrolling until the keyboard is not closed. The xml code is as below, any further code can be posted on request.

EDIT: using adjustResize in manifest solves the problem of hidden Actionbar but leaves a whitespace one fourth the size of the screen once the keyboard is discarded. Possibly because it is resizing the Recyclerview as well?

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_done" />

<SearchView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:background="@color/gray2Background"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="36dp"></SearchView>
```

Comment: Hi, how did you solved the problem? Can you share your solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In manifest try to add this line in the activity:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustNothing"
```

It may be helpful.